# How to create/build multiple instances of a factory in Factory Girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

How do I create multiple records or multiple factories of the same class?

I tried:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "someuser@somesite.com"
  user.password "somepassword"

  user.email "another_existing_user@somesite.com"
  user.password "somepassword"
end
```

and

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "someuser@somesite.com"
  user.password "somepassword"
end

Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.email "another_existing_user@somesite.com"
  user.password "somepassword"
end
```

But it doesn't work -- `Attribute already defined: email`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two steps to using Factories, the first is to define them, and the second is to use them.

1) Define Them:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.sequence(:email) { |n| "mike#{n}@awesome.com"}
  u.password "password123"
end
```

2) Using Them:

An example would be to use them in a spec:

```
 @user1 = Factory(:user) #has an email of mike1@awesome.com
 @user2 = Factory(:user) # has an email of mike2@awesome.com due to sequences in FG
```

I'd watch this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures) to get a better feel for it.

Answer (score 49):

This is an older question and answer but it was the first result I found on Google so I thought I would add the following from the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#building-or-creating-multiple-records) under the heading **Building or Creating Multiple Records**:

```
created_users = FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 25)  #creates 25 users

twenty_year_olds = FactoryBot.build_list(:user, 25, date_of_birth: 20.years.ago)  #builds 25 users, sets their date_of_birth
```

If you want to run this in the rails console, consider the following answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23580836/4880924

In the example I just cited, each user would have a different username, provided that `sequence` is used in the factory definition (see Mike Lewis' answer above).

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for coming back to an old question and giving an updated answer.

Answer (score 37):

There's a couple of options if you want records from the same (base) factory to have different values.

**A)** Override defined attributes

```
factory :post, aliases: [:approved_post] do
  title "A title"
  approved true
end

approved_post = create(:approved_post)
unapproved_post = create(:post, approved: false)
```

**B)** Inheritance

```
factory :post do
  title "A title"

  factory :approved_post do
    approved true
  end

  factory :unapproved_post do
    approved false
  end
end

approved_post = create(:approved_post)
unapproved_post = create(:unapproved_post)
```

**C)** Sequences

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:email, 1000) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
end
```

**D)** Traits

```
factory :post do
  title "My awesome title"

  trait(:approved) { approved true }

  trait(:unapproved) { approved false }

  trait :with_comments do
    after(:create) do |instance|
      create_list :comment, 2, post: instance
    end
  end

  factory :approved_post_with_comments, traits: [:approved, :with_comments]
end

approved_post_with_comments = create(:approved_post_with_comments)
unapproved_post_with_no_comments = create(:post, :unapproved, title: "Test")
post_with_title = build(:post)
```

---

These methods can be combined. This example uses lists and pairs with sequences and overriding.

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:username) { |n| "user#{n}" }
  date_of_birth Date.today
end

# Build a pair and a list of users.
two_newborns     = build_pair(:user)
ten_young_adults = build_list(:user, 10, date_of_birth: 20.years.ago)

# Create a pair and a list of users.
two_young_adults = create_pair(:user, date_of_birth: 20.years.ago)
ten_newborns     = create_list(:user, 10)
```

I prefer to use traits whenever possible, I find them flexible.

Answer (score 0):

With the current `factory_girl_rails` 4.6.0 I had the somehow related problem that `build(:model)` returned always the same instance of the object. Using `sequence(:name) ...` didn't fix that. So I generated some fake (empty) traits like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
     ...
     # fake traits to urge factory_girl to always return a new instance:
    (1..5).each {|n| trait "var#{n}".to_sym }
  end
end
```

And then calling `build(:model, :var1), build(:model, :var2)...`