# How do I use factories from FactoryBot in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using rails console in the development environment and I want to use factories.  How can I get access to them?

I have tried `require "FactoryBot"` which returns

```
1.9.3p393 :301 > require "FactoryBot"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- FactoryBot
```

Comment: These are all in test, I want to do it in development

Comment: you'd probably want to start with a require 'factory_girl' rather than requiring the FactoryGirl constant.

Comment: adjusting for current times - you can start `rails c` then do a `require 'factory_bot'`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To solve this problem ensure that the factory bot gem is specifed in your Gemfile similar to this

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

Then `bundle install`.

This should make FactoryBot class available in the development console.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adding FactoryGirl in gemfile like this instead of `gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false` will throw errors for anyone trying to set up development environment from scratch, beware.

Comment: This answer works, but the accepted answer should be `rails console test`, it will allow you to create a console in the test environment so you don't need to update your Gemfile to use a test package in the development environment

Answer (score 244):

I do this the following way:

- Start the rails console in test environment in sandbox mode.

  ```
  rails console -e test --sandbox
  ```

You need this for two reasons:

1. Any changes you do are rolled back.
2. If you already have some seed data it might happen that the factories will start the serialization of attributes from 1, but these records might already exist.

Then in the console:

- Require FactoryBot (was called FactoryGirl):

  ```
  require 'factory_bot'
  ```
- Load the factory definitions:

  ```
  FactoryBot.find_definitions
  ```
- Include the FactoryBot methods to avoid prefixing all calls to FB with `FactoryBot` (`create` instead of `FactoryBot.create`):

  ```
  include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  ```

P.S. For [fabrication gem](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) you can load the definitions in the rails console with:

```
Fabrication.manager.load_definitions
```

Also `require 'faker'` if you use it.

Comment: Should that last line be `require 'ffaker'`?

Comment: It depends on which gem you use - faker or ffaker, but I agree that lately ffaker is more widely used.

Comment: I've faced undefined method `fixture_file_upload` issue, that was caused by absence of `ActionDispatch::TestProcess` module, so you might consider including it also

Comment: If you're restarting the console a lot, here's a one-liner: `require "factory_bot_rails"; include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods; require 'ffaker'`

Comment: Rails 5.1.6, just with either `rails console test` or `rails console test --sandbox` will work. If you don't like using the `FactoryBot` prefix, do include Syntax Methods

Comment: For Rails 6.0 run the console like this: `rails c -e test --sandbox`

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's not necessary to run it in the test env. Otherwise the instructions are good.

Answer (score 26):

You need to `require 'factory_bot_rails'`, which is the actual gem that's being used by Rails. That gem will include the Factory Bot library, making `FactoryBot` available.

You can either do this, or update your Gemfile to require it at startup as in muttonlamb's answer.

Comment: Because I was using Faker in my factories, I also had to run `require 'faker'`.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to have it available each time you start the console, you can add this piece of code to the top of your config/environments/development.rb:

```rb
require 'factory_bot_rails'
require 'faker' # if you're also using faker gem
require 'rails/console/helpers'
Rails::ConsoleMethods.prepend(FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods)
```

Now you can use the built-in helpers right after starting the console, for example:

```rb
company = create(:company)
```

Comment: For Rails 6, this answer is close–the previous answers didn't work. I only needed to run `Rails::ConsoleMethods.prepend(FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods)` (and not the previous three `require`s) to get it to work (I don't use `faker`).

Comment: @EdRuder if you have those gems in `development` group in Gemfile, then you're right - they should be required automatically.