# Define multiple custom records using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a hash of key and values that I would like to be created using FactoryGirl. I went through a [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509790/how-to-create-build-multiple-instances-of-a-factory-in-factory-girl) with similar requirements, but couldn't understand a way to achieve what I want. Following is what I tried:

```
statuses = {
  "holding_status" => "Holding",
  "scheduled_status" => "Scheduled",
  "submitted_status" => "Submitted",
  "cancelled_status" => "Cancelled",
  "failed_status" => "Failed",
  "none_status" => nil
}

statuses.each do |code, name|
  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :submit_statuses do
      code code
      name name
    end
  end
end
```

But, it gives me the following error(expected):

> /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.5.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in
>   `method_missing': Factory already registered:
>   submit_statuses (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)

**EDIT** (Another Try)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  statuses.each do |code, name|
    factory "submit_#{code}" do
      code code
      name name
    end
  end
end

create(:submit_holding_status)
create(:submit_scheduled_status)
create(:submit_submitted_status)
create(:submit_cancelled_status)
create(:submit_failed_status)
create(:submit_none_status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you expect to be able to call this factory? I'm a little unclear what you're hoping to achieve here.

One possible approach I would recommend is to define each status type as a [factory trait](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits):

```
statuses = {
  "holding_status" => "Holding",
  "scheduled_status" => "Scheduled",
  "submitted_status" => "Submitted",
  "cancelled_status" => "Cancelled",
  "failed_status" => "Failed",
  "none_status" => nil
}

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :submit_status do
    statuses.each do |code, name|
      trait code.to_sym do
        code code
        name name
      end
    end
  end
end

# Usage:
FactoryGirl.create(:submit_status, :holding_status)

# Or:
statuses.map { |status| FactoryGirl.create(:submit_status, status) }
```

Comment: yep, actually better interpretation of OP.

Comment: Just to understand, can you please see my **EDIT** and tell me what is the advantage of `trait` over my code

Comment: Your new code is *valid*, but I would consider it poor quality. You are polluting the global namespace of factories, which only seems OK because every status code is called `<something>_status` ... But why *IS* everything named like that? Your statuses should just be `holding`, `scheduled`, `submitted`, etc. By using traits, you can logically group each factory under one "title".

Comment: I would also suggest defining the list of statuses as a constant (perhaps  `SubmitStatus::Types`?), not with this variable being re-defined in multiple places. But that's a separate issue.